# Monad laws for an applicative-based formulation

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

Normally in Haskell we define `Monad`s in terms of `return` and `>>=`. Sometimes it's convenient to decompose `>>=` into `fmap` and `join`. The `Monad` laws for these two formulations are well known and fairly intuitive, once you get used to them.

There's another way to define monads, in terms of an `Applicative` functor:

```
class Applicative f => MyMonad f where
    myJoin :: f (f a) -> f a
```

I'm wondering about the laws for this kind of formulation. Obviously, we *could* just adapt the `fmap` + `join` laws, as follows (I am not sure the names are particularly apt, but oh well):

```
myJoin . myJoin = myJoin . (pure myJoin <*>)       ('Associativity')
myJoin . pure   = myJoin . (pure pure   <*>) = id  ('Identity')
```

Clearly these conditions are sufficient for `pure`, `(<*>)`, and `myJoin` to form a monad (in the sense that they guarantee that `` m `myBind` f = myJoin (pure f <*> m) `` will be a well-behaved `>>=`). **But are they necessary as well?** It seems at least possible that the additional structure that `Applicative` supports above and beyond `Functor` might allow us to simplify these laws -- in other words, that some feature of the above laws might be otiose given that it is known that `pure` and `(<*>)` already satisfy the `Applicative` laws.

(In case you're wondering why we'd even go to the trouble of bothering with this formulation given either of the two standard possibilities: I'm not sure it's all that useful or perspicuous in programming contexts, but it turns out to be so when you use `Monad`s to [do natural langauge semantics](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0205026).)

Answer (score 2):

The identity law is much easier to write

```
join . fmap pure = join . pure = id
```

The traditional monad right identity law follows immediately from the definition of `>>=`. The left identity law uses an `Applicative` law

```
m >>= k = join (fmap k m)

-- proof for right identity
m >>= return       = m
join (fmap pure m) = m  -- definition of >>=
id m               = m  -- identity
m                  = m  -- definition of id

-- proof for left identity
return a >>= f         = f a
join (fmap f (pure a)) = f a  -- definitions of >>= and return
join (pure (f a))      = f a  -- fmap f . pure = pure . f
id (f a)               = f a  -- identity
f a                    = f a  -- definition of id
```

The interesting law for a relationship between `Applicative` and `Monad` is

```
(<*>) = ap
-- or
m1 <*> m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= \x2 -> return (x1 x2)) -- definition of ap
```

In terms of `Applicative` and `join` this is

```
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> fmap x1 m2) m1)
-- proof
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> m2 >>= \x2 -> return (x1 x2)) m1)            -- definition of ap
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> join (fmap (\x2 -> return (x1 x2)) m2)) m1)  -- definition of >>=
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> join (fmap (\x2 -> pure (x1 x2)) m2)) m1)    -- return = pure
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> join (fmap (pure . x1) m2)) m1)                 
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> join (fmap pure (fmap x1 m2))) m1)           -- fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g
m1 <*> m2 = join (fmap (\x1 -> fmap x1 m2) m1)                              -- identity
```

There might be a more elegant way to write this.

I haven't found a way to show that the `Monad` is associative based on

- `Functor` and `Applicative` laws - particularly composition of `<*>`
- The identities `join . fmap pure = join . pure = id`
- `(<*>) = ap`

and I'm not sure if it's true. I think you need the associative law `join . join = join . fmap join`

Comment: `>>=` is not associative in general, because its type `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` isn't symmetric. `(a >>= b) >>= c` will type check as long as `a ~ b`, but `a >>= (b >>= c)` would require something along the lines of `m c ~ a -> m b`.

Comment: `m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  =  (m >>= k) >>= h` _is_ the associative law from the Kleisli category with arrows `a -> m b`, it's just written poorly. `a >=> (b >=> c) = (a >=> b) >=> c`

Comment: This is very helpful. (There is a small typo in your second definition of `<*>`: you write `=>>` twice where you mean `>>=`.)